# How to know the orientation angle of real Sense depth Camera?

Tags: orientation, intel, realsense, d3dimage

How to know the orientation angle of real Sense depth camera? i.e. if it is kept horizontal or vertical?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several realsense cameras.
In the bottom of the following link there is the description of SR300 and D400-series:

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/wiki/Projection-in-RealSense-SDK-2.0#d400